# Mercurial convert with filemap to separate subfolders creates empty repository

Tags: mercurial, repository, filemap

I have a large Hg repository (2+GB) that was converted from an svn repository. It has a number of websites in it, and we want to separate those out into separate Hg repos. The repositories are on a Windows 2008 Server and we're using the hg that comes with TortoiseHg.

We've been trying to use the convert method with a filemap to create a new repo from the converted repository.

The problem is that the command runs through all the changesets in the source repo, but the newly created repo is empty.

This is what the command line looks like:

```
hg convert -s hg --filemap "hgsplitstaticsites-site1.txt" staticsites-hg "C:\projects\marcelsprojects\hgversions\site1-hg"
```

The filemap looks like this:

```
include staticsites-hg/site1
rename staticsites-hg/site1 .
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

we've also tried running hg convert on the subfolder in the svn repository, but that actually throws an exception and exits.

---

We gave up on this one, and just separated the sub folders into separate Hg repos, and lost all of the version history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a batch script to help with running the `hg convert` command.  [Can I clone part of a Mercurial repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745000/can-i-clone-part-of-a-mercurial-repository/4996790#4996790)

Comment: We don't need to use that anymore, but it looks like a nice little workaround. Thanks for posting that.

Answer (score 3):

I also just had the problem with the empty repository. The problem in my case was that I used Windows-style path names (with backslash instead of a normal slash) in my filemap like this:

```
include src\file1.pas
include src\file2.pas
...
```

But it had to be in the POSIX format:

```
include src/file1.pas
include src/file2.pas
...
```

Apparently you also may not prepend `./` to the path as it produced an empty repository as well.

Your filemap looks okay, so this could not have been the cause in your case, but maybe this will help others who are having this problem and find this page through Google.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574371/empty-repository-after-subversion-mercurial-conversion) was spot on: you don't actually create an empty directory, but a directory with a hidden `.hg` directory. If you run

```
hg update
```

in your target directory, you will have your target directory with all its contents as expected.

Answer (score 1):

My problem with empty repository was due to pathnames in the filemap were of the wrong case.

Comment: I can't remember if that may have been the issue or if I tried that as a fix, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `hg convert`? What do you mean by empty repository? If you do `hg log` in target repository, do you have any entries?

Comment: Empty repository means that it creates a folder called 'site1-hg' with a .hg folder in it, so it's a valid Hg repo, but if I open the repository browsers, there are no changesets, and the browser says 'Empty Repository' at the bottom. Update is disabled, because there's nothing to update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it's caused by your include line. You need to specify relative path, not the repository one..

E.g

```
svnrepo > branches |
        | tags     |
        | trunk    > Project1
                   | Project2
```

Your filemap should look like this

include Project1

Comment: Thanks for the update. Hopefully we won't need to convert any more svn repos, but if we ever do, that fix might be very helpful.