# hg convert with filemap giving empty repository

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgsubversion

I have got a new repository converted from SVN. I want to minimize this repository further by removing unintended files.
For that I am again converting the mercurial repository to a new one by using `hg convert` and the `filemap` parameter.
So my filemap looks like this:

```
include a
rename a .
```

The command I am using is:

```
hg convert --filemap fm.txt . ../new_repo
```

This ends after full conversion as I can see in the console output.

But if I now check the content of the directory new repo, I can see only .hg files in there.

I ran `hg update -C`  within the directory whic gives me one more file `.hgtags`

Can anyone please suggest what has gone wrong?

Comment: Test and how `hg log` in `new_repo` dir

Comment: hg log shows me all the intended logs and seems to be fine. Except the files.

Comment: You **have** repo and have to update only working dir - see my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574371/empty-repository-after-subversion-mercurial-conversion) was spot on: you don't actually create an empty directory, but a directory with a hidden `.hg` directory. If you run

```
hg update
```

in your target directory, you will have your target directory with all its contents as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In common, you done all correct (if directory `a` exist in source repo)

In my test for repository with directory lang, which I want to move into the root of new repo, I used filemap

```
include lang
rename lang .
```

identical to your filemap and got bare repository after converting (no files in Working Dir, only repository on .hg). Testing repository

```
hg log
changeset:   19:41e96453fa67
tag:         tip
...
changeset:   0:ba52ea5c5c1f
```

showed me all related hisory

```
hg up
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

(**without `-C`**) brings all files into the Working Directory

```
SR>dir /B
.hg
UTF-8
```

Comment: "hg up" on the working directory fetches me another file ".hgtags" having entries like:
__b108468eca7d6522a911e1cafbcecae6d380bbd2 svn.3502__

Comment: I figured out, that the hg workbench has two branches: "Branches" which came from SVN and the "default". How can I remove "Branches" branch and get everything in "default" branch?

Comment: @Kallol - you can't remove any branch in Mercurial. you can close "Branches" branch, or just ignore it and work in default only (`hg up default`, work and commit)